# How can I get Visual Studio 2008 english language pack?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am currently using VS 2008 Professional German edition. I wish to change my UI to English. 
Under Options--> Internationale Einstellungen, I am unable to set English. 
My OS is Win2k3 english. Setting the language to 'Wie Microsoft Windows' also does not help.

I get a message stating I need to reset the environment. Do not know how to proceed.

Is there a way to download and install VS 2008 english language pack?
I am unable to find any download links upon googling.

Please help, 
Praseo

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Tools menu and choose Options...
Check the Show all settings check box at the bottom left of the screen 
Click the International Settings option under the Environment item in the tree control on the left side of the Options dialog
Select English in the Language drop down
Click OK to confirm the language change and then press OK on the notification dialog that appears to indicate that the IDE must be restarted for the change to take effect
Close and reopen the IDE

Comment: 'English' is not listed in the drop down menu.

Comment: Sorry to say, I am unable to download CLIP. It only downloads an html file which has instructions in all languages. No drop down menu or download link exists.